# Center any amount of divs inside a parent div with CSS

Tags: css, alignment, center

I have a parent DIV (a menu bar) with a random number of child divs. I'm looking for a clean, simple CSS that will always center the child divs horizontally, regardless of their width or the number of divs (as long as they fit inside the parent). I don't want to have to calculate all the widths or use absolute positioning.

After looking at several solutions I came up with this code, but the child divs still don't center properly, especially when you fill them with text or images.

**HTML:**

```
<div id="menubar">
   <div id="button">too much text will offset the other buttons</div>
   <div id="button">b2</div>
   <div id="button">b3</div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#menubar {
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0px;
    background-color: #00A0E2;
    width:100%; height:80px;
    text-align:center;
} 

#button {
    margin: 5px auto 5px auto;
    width:120px;height:70px;
    display:inline-block;
    background-color:white;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

I have created this JSFiddle to illustrate my problem: http://jsfiddle.net/mZ2P2/

Comment: Those are correctly (horizontally) centered for me. Did you mean they should be centered *vertically*?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to `vertical-align` the inline elements so that they display correctly when they do not have the same height. Here's a [working example](http://jsfiddle.net/wVA7N/1/). I also removed the `id` attribute of your buttons and changed it for a `class`.

**EDIT:** jsfiddle.net is not working all that well for me right now. The change introduced was `vertical-align: top` to the `.button` class.

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you use an unordered list and then use the css to position them in the center.

Comment: I need horizontal centering, see the JSFiddle that I added. Can I use unordered lists to achieve this?

Comment: Check this out http://jsbin.com/avuhep/1/edit You can edit the ul and li according to your needs.

Comment: Sorry, I got confused a little..looks like someone has already given you the answer.

Comment: As far as I can see that is still vertical centering. The answer above is working though.