# Jquery animation ends up in flicker

Tags: jquery, html, animation

I am having trouble in getting an animation like one shown in link below

http://www.davidbo.dreamhosters.com/plugins/mediaBoxes/example/demo4.html

I have tried animate(), hide() and display() functions but ended up in a flicker. i need the animations like one shown when categories are clicked.

```
<section class="recent_work">
<h1>RECENT WORKS</h1>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed et quam <br> est. Mauris faucibus tellus ac auctor posuere. </p>
<ul class="menu_bar">
<li id="ALL" class="all">ALL</li>
<li id="WEB" class="web">WEB</li>
<li id="MOBILE" class="mobile">MOBILE</li>
<li id="PHOTOGRAPHY" class="photography">PHOTOGRAPHY</li>
<li id="DESIGN" class="design">DESIGN</li>
<li id="TYPE" class="type">TYPE</li>
</ul>
<ul class="work_samples">
<li><a href="#" class="design"><img src="images/recent work/design.png" />
<h2>title</h2>
<p>please describe the<br> product</p>
</a>
</li>
<li><a href="#" class="mobile"><img src="images/recent work/mobile.png" />
<h2>title</h2>
<p>please describe the<br> product</p></a></li>
<li><a href="#" class="photography"><img src="images/recent work/photography.png" />
<h2>title</h2>
<p>please describe the<br> product</p></a></li>
<li><a href="#" class="type"><img src="images/recent work/type.png" />
<h2>title</h2>
<p>please describe the<br> product</p></a></li>
<li><a href="#" class="web"><img src="images/recent work/web2.png" />
<h2>title</h2>
<p>please describe the<br> product</p></a></li>
<li><a href="#" class="web"><img src="images/recent work/web.png" />
<h2>title</h2>
<p>please describe the<br> product</p></a></li>
</ul>
</section>


.recent_work{
background-color:#9ad4a6;
}
.work_samples h2,.work_samples p{
text-align:center;
}
.recent_work h1{
font-family: Lato-Bold;
font-size: 64px;
text-align: center;
margin: 0px auto;
padding: 50px 0px 0px 0px;
color:#ffffff;
}
.recent_work p{
font-family: Lato;
text-align: center;
color: #ffffff;
font-size: 20px;
padding: 10px;
}
.work_samples a{
margin: 30px;
display: inline-block;
text-decoration:none;
}
.menu_bar li{
display:inline;
list-style:none;
margin:0px 10px;
padding:10px 21px;
COLOR:#FFFFFF;
font-family:Lato-Bold;
font-size:22px;
border:3px solid #9ad4a6;
cursor:pointer;
}
.menu_bar{
margin: 98px auto 20px;
text-align:center;
}
.menu_bar li:HOVER
{
border:3px solid #ffffff;
border-radius:10px
}
.work_samples{
display:block;
max-width: 950px;
margin: 0px auto;
}
.work_samples li{
list-style:none;
display:inline-block;
}


$(document).ready(function(e){
$(".menu_bar>li").hover(function(){
$(this).css({"border":"3px solid #fff","border-radius":"10px"});
},function(){
$(this).css({"border":"3px solid #9ad4a6","border-radius":"10px"});
});

$("#ALL").css({"background":"#fff","border-        radius":"10px","color":"#a3a3a3","border":"3px solid #fff"});

$(".menu_bar>li").click(function (event) {
event.preventDefault()
$(".menu_bar>li").css({"background-color":"#9ad4a6","color":"#fff","border":"3px solid #9ad4a6"});
$(this).animate({'background-color':'#fff',"border-radius":"10px","color":"#a3a3a3","border":"3px solid #fff"});
var classname=$(this).text().toLowerCase();
$('.'+classname).show(0);
$(".work_samples>li>a").not($('.'+classname)).hide(500);


if(classname=='all')
{$(".work_samples>li>a").show(500);}
});
```

Comment: Show us your code/what you tried. Maybe create a JSfiddle also.

Comment: I meant the html and the jquery code...

Comment: i have added all html css and jquerry please scroll down to have a look

Comment: I got something working, but it's more or less similar to the plugin you posted.. The fade out / fade in animations are there, but the smooth repositioning of the boxes is not. At the bottom of the page you posted, the developper mentions that he uses Isotope. This plugin is great and does the smooth position if I recall correctly. If you really wish to have the exact same effect, I can try and make it work. Other than that, do you wish to see what I came up with? Maybe you'll like it. Comment back if you want me to post my answer.

Comment: Thinking of it... you might want to test [ISOTOPE](http://isotope.metafizzy.co/) yourself. I realized I kind of does exactly the same effect you are looking for. I don't know why I didn't think about this sooner, but by checking the first demo on their page, it struck me. Sometimes re-inventing the wheel is not always the solution. When something already exist, and if it works really good, why try to do it again? I guess I wanted a good challenge to test my knowledge, but in the end the solution was not really far. I'll let you decide.

Comment: hi thanks for having a look IndieRok please post the answer

Comment: Damn, gonna need to put that on hold.. I don't know why but everything was working fine on my desktop PC at work and now on my PC at home, it's not working as intended. Sorry about that. I'll let you know if I get this to work as it was supposed to, but in the mean time, I guess Isotope is your best bet.

Answer (score 1):

So, I don't know if you still want to see this. Anyway, after a few tweaking here and there, I managed to get something to my liking. I changed your html and css a bit, I hope you won't mind. In this kind of situation, I prefer to use DIVs rather than an UL>LI. You'll see why. I also like to divide content into separate divs.

First of all, I searched a bit and found a way to have all the divs stay centered all the time. This means that, if someone resize the browser, the divs will always be centered and practically equally distributed by rows. [SOURCE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14384407/center-any-amount-of-divs-inside-a-parent-div-with-css)

[WORKING EXAMPLE](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/xlEny)

Here is the new html. Notice how all divs in the '.items-container' possess a different amount of classes. These classes will define a filter, so make sure to give all divs their relevant classes. Except the class "item" which is mandatory for all.

```
<section class="recent_work">
    <div class="top-container">
        <h1>RECENT WORKS</h1>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed et quam <br> est. Mauris faucibus tellus ac auctor posuere. </p>
        <ul class="menu_bar">
            <li id="ALL" data-filter="all" class="active-item">ALL</li>
            <li id="WEB" data-filter="web">WEB</li>
            <li id="MOBILE" data-filter="mobile">MOBILE</li>
            <li id="PHOTOGRAPHY" data-filter="photography">PHOTOGRAPHY</li>
            <li id="DESIGN" data-filter="design">DESIGN</li>
            <li id="TYPE" data-filter="type">TYPE</li>
        </ul>
    </div>

    <div class="middle-container">

        <div class="items-container">
            <div class="item design">
                <a href="#">
                    <!-- <img src="images/recent work/design.png" /> -->
                    <h2>title</h2>
                    <p>please describe<br/>the product</p>
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="item mobile type">
                <a href="#">
                    <!-- <img src="images/recent work/mobile.png" /> -->
                    <h2>title</h2>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="item photography design web type">
                <a href="#">
                    <!-- <img src="images/recent work/photography.png" /> -->
                    <h2>title</h2>
                    <p>Hello world</p>
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="item type design">
                <a href="#">
                    <!-- <img src="images/recent work/type.png" /> -->
                    <h2>title</h2>
                    <p>Hola amigo</p>
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="item web">
                <a href="#">
                    <!-- <img src="images/recent work/web2.png" /> -->
                    <h2>title</h2>
                    <p>Very nice day</p>
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="item web type">
                <a href="#">
                    <!-- <img src="images/recent work/web.png" /> -->
                    <h2>title</h2>
                    <p>I like web</p>
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="item design web">
                <a href="#">
                    <!-- <img src="images/recent work/design.png" /> -->
                    <h2>title</h2>
                    <p>A cup of tea please</p>
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="item mobile web photography">
                <a href="#">
                    <!-- <img src="images/recent work/mobile.png" /> -->
                    <h2>title</h2>
                    <p>Donde esta?</p>
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="item photography design mobile">
                <a href="#" class=" s">
                    <!-- <img src="images/recent work/photography.png" /> -->
                    <h2>title</h2>
                    <p>Gd'ay Mate!</p>
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="item type mobile web">
                <a href="#" class=" s">
                    <!-- <img src="images/recent work/type.png" /> -->
                    <h2>title</h2>
                    <p>Bonjour cher ami!</p>
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

Next, on to the animation. The animation is really simple, on the click of a menu LI, I get its custom attribute which contains a filter/class name. Step 1 is to target all divs and scale them to 0. Step 2, apply a CSS which will display none all divs. Step 3, we take the filter name and we target all divs which possess this class name and reset their display property. Step 4, all the targeted element will be rescaled to default and realigned perfectly side by side and centered.

Here is the final Jquery code:

```
$(function () {
    $(".menu_bar>li").hover(function(){
        $(this).css({"border":"3px solid #fff","border-radius":"10px"});
    },function(){
        $(this).css({"border":"3px solid #9ad4a6","border-radius":"10px"});
    });

    $(".menu_bar li").click(function (event) {

        //Prevent animation on already active button
        if($(this).hasClass('active-item')){
            return false;
        }

        //Set active menu item style
        $(".menu_bar li").removeClass('active-item');
        $(this).addClass('active-item');

        var classname = $(this).attr('data-filter');

        if(classname=='all')
        {
            //Scale to 0 all boxes
            $('.item').addClass('hide-item');

            setTimeout(function(){
                //Change opacity and display property of all boxes we do not want to show
                $('.hide-item').addClass('hide-my-box');

                setTimeout(function(){
                    //Reset to default opacity and display property of all boxes we want to show
                    $('.item').removeClass('hide-my-box');

                    //Scale to default all boxes we want to show
                    setTimeout(function(){
                        $('.item').removeClass('hide-item');
                    }, 10);
                }, 200);                
            }, 200);

        }
        else{
            //Scale to 0 all boxes
            $('.item').addClass('hide-item');

            setTimeout(function(){
                //Change opacity and display property of all boxes we do not want to show
                $('.hide-item').addClass('hide-my-box');

                setTimeout(function(){
                    //Reset to default opacity and display property of all boxes we want to show
                    $('.'+classname).removeClass('hide-my-box');

                    //Scale to default all boxes we want to show
                    setTimeout(function(){
                        $('.'+classname).removeClass('hide-item');
                    }, 10);
                }, 200);                
            }, 200);
        }
    });
});
```

The Css:

```
*{
    margin:9;
    padding: 0;
}

body{
    height: 100%;
}

html{
    background-color:#9ad4a6;
}

.recent_work{
    background-color:#9ad4a6;
    height: 100%;
}
.work_samples h2,.work_samples p{
    text-align:center;
}

.recent_work h1{
    font-family: Lato-Bold;
    font-size: 64px;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0px auto;
    padding: 50px 0px 0px 0px;
    color:#ffffff;
}

.recent_work p{
    font-family: Lato;
    text-align: center;
    color: #ffffff;
    font-size: 20px;
    padding: 10px;
}

.menu_bar li{
    display:inline-block;
    list-style:none;
    margin:0px 10px;
    padding:10px 21px;
    COLOR:#FFFFFF;
    font-family:Lato-Bold;
    font-size:22px;
    border:3px solid #9ad4a6;
    cursor:pointer;
}

.menu_bar{
    margin: 98px auto 20px;
    text-align:center;
}

.menu_bar li:HOVER
{
    border:3px solid #ffffff;
    border-radius:10px
}

.active-item{
    background:#fff;
    border-radius:10px;
    color:#a3a3a3 !important;
    border:3px solid #fff !important;
}

.hide-item{
    transform: scale(0);
    -webkit-transform: scale(0);
    -o-transform: scale(0); 
    -moz-transform: scale(0);
}

.hide-my-box{
    display: none !important;
    -webkit-transition: opacity .3s ease-out;
    opacity: 0; 
}

.top-container{
    position: relative;
    display: block;
}

.middle-container{
    position: relative;
    margin-top: 50px;
    margin-bottom: 50px;
    height: 100%;
}

.items-container{
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0px;
    width:100%;
    text-align:center;
    height:100%;
}

.item{
    margin: 15px;
    width:250px;
    height: 200px;
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
    background: #ebebeb;
    -webkit-transition: .3s all ease-in-out;
   -moz-transition: .3s all ease-in-out;
   -o-transition: .3s all ease-in-out;
   transition: .3s all ease-in-out;
   border:1px solid;
}

.item p{
    color:#000;
}
```

Comment: P.S. sorry if it took so long, but my home computer needs hardware update and is sucky in the moment, so I didn't want to work on this in the weekend.

Comment: If you have any questions about the code, don't hesitate to ask!